# Sequelize orm why not working?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to relate two tables.

The two tables are the employee table and the department table.

But for some reason the relationship is not made.

Here is my code and the error. What am I doing wrong?

I want to have multiple department tables in the employee table.

It works fine if I do not include it inside findAll. However, including them will cause problems.

```js
//

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {    
    const department = sequelize.define('DEPT', {
        deptNo: {
            field: 'DEPTNO',
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER ,
            primaryKey: true ,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        deptName: { 
            field: 'DEPTNAME',
            type: DataTypes.STRING(32)            
        },
        floor: { 
            field: 'FLOOR',
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
    }, {
            // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
            // so updatedAt will be updated_at
            underscored: true,
            // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
            // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
            // if you don't want that, set the following
            freezeTableName: true,
            // define the table's name

            tableName: 'DEPARTMENT'
        });

        department.associate = function (models){   
            department.belongsTo(models.EMP , {
                foreignkey : "empId"
            });
            
        };
    return department;
}




module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {    

    const employee = sequelize.define('EMP', {
        empNo: {
            field: 'EMPNO',
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER ,
            primaryKey: true ,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        empName: { 
            field: 'EMPNAME',
            type: DataTypes.STRING(32)            
        },
        title: { 
            field: 'TITLE',
            type: DataTypes.STRING(32)     
        },
        dNo: {
            field: 'DNO',
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER            
        },
        salary: {
            field: 'SALARY',
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    }, {
            // don't use camelcase for automatically added attributes but underscore style
            // so updatedAt will be updated_at
            underscored: true,
            // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
            // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
            // if you don't want that, set the following
            freezeTableName: true,
            // define the table's name

            tableName: 'EMPLOYEE'
        });        
        
        employee.associations = function (models) {
            employee.hasMany(models.DEPT , {
                foreignkey : "empId"
            });
        };
    return employee;
}


router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {    
    models.EMP.findAll({
        include : [{model :models.DEPT}]
    })
    .then(results => {
        res.json(results);
     })
     .catch( err => {
         console.error(err);
     });
});
```

ERROR : SequelizeEagerLoadingError: DEPT is not associated to EMP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have smth like this:

```
const models = {};

glob.sync(path.join(__dirname, 'path to models e.g. **/*.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(file);
    models[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(models).forEach(model => {
  if (models[model].associate) {
    models[model].associate(models);
  }
});


export {models};
```